# Choosing co-efficients from a restricted set to ensure a vector is orthogonal to another

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\vec{u} = (p_1u_1,...,p_nu_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $p_i \in \{-1,1\}$.  Let $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Is there a systematic way to choose $p_i$ such that $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = 0$, or to show that for the two given vectors that is not possible?

Comment: I assume the $u_i$ are given alongside $\overrightarrow{v}$?

Comment: yes, both are known

Comment: Presumably you mean without evaluating all $2^n$ possibilities, which would be slow (but systematic!)?

Comment: Yes, I do in fact mean that, although if that's the only option I'll take it.  $n$ is typically small in my problem, less than 10 or so, so I guess that's definitely one way to do it.

Comment: If this is a computational technique, and $n$ is small, then I would suggest that a simple 'dumb' technique is better and if performance becomes an issue then focus on improvements.

Comment: That's true, and I'll take what I can get if that's the only option.  However, the actual problem I'll eventually be facing is to choose $\vec{u}$ such that the solution exists (so I'll need to find the solution as well, but the vector will have to be such that the solution exists in the first place.  In that case, the computation solution will solve the problem of choosing the solution once I know it exists, but it won't help to know it exists

Comment: If you let $\alpha_i = u_i v_i$ the question can be posed as checking if there is a $p$ (satisfying the $\pm 1$ constraint) such that $p \cdot \alpha = 0$. (Edit: I wrote this before your last comment.) You can view this as a 'weighing scale' sort of problem.

Comment: Note Robert's answer below, in particular the fact that this is NP-complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstractly, one an notice that the space of vectors perpendicular to $(p_1u_1,\ldots,p_nu_n)$ is a subspace of dimension $n-1$ (unless all the $u_i=0$). There are $2^n$ possible choices of $p_n$, so the set of vectors $v$ perpendicular to any of them is the union of $2^n$ such subspaces (although, since opposite choices of $p_n$ yield the same subspace, it can actually be written as a union of $2^{n-1}$ subspaces). One can show that $\mathbb R^n$ is not the union of any finite number of subspaces and, in fact, that in some senses *most* vectors $v$ are not perpendicular to such a vector.

More explicitly, let $\overrightarrow{v}=(1,0,0,0,0,\ldots,0)$ and $\overrightarrow{u}=(1,1,1,1,1,\ldots,1)$. Then, the dot product is $p_1,$ which can clearly never be zero.

---

As for finding such a set of $p_i$, this is exactly the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). In particular, if we let $v'=(u_1v_1,u_2v_2,\ldots,u_nv_n)$, then we are looking to partition the multiset represented by $v'$ into two subsets which have equal sum. In particular, if $S$ and $T$ form a partition of the indices $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ into two subsets such that
$$\sum_{s\in S}u_sv_s=\sum_{t\in T}u_tv_T$$
then we have
$$\sum_{s\in S}u_sv_s-\sum_{t\in T}u_tv_T=0$$
thus, setting $p_i$ to $1$ where $i\in S$ and to $-1$ when $i\in T$ suffices to solve the problem. The Wikipedia page lists various algorithms for solving this problem.

Comment: So that helps with the second part (if it is possible that the combination cannot exist).  Any thoughts on the first part (to find such a combination if it exists) without exhaustive search?  I feel that, from your original answer, the problem reduces to a dot product $\vec{p}\vec{d}$, where $\vec{d}$ are the elements of the dot product of u and v.  Then $p \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$, although I'm not sure how that helps...

Answer (score 3):

$\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}$ is a linear function of the $p_i$, say $\sum_{i} a_i p_i$.  You want to partition $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ into two subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $\sum_{i \in A} a_i = \sum_{i \in B} a_i$.  In the version where the $a_i$ are integers, this is the [Set Partitioning Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).  That is NP-complete, so you won't find an efficient algorithm.  However, there are 
algorithms that find good approximate solutions quickly.  If the $a_i$ are
all small multiples of some number, the pseudo-polynomial dynamic programming algorithm might be useful.